# What is the global command for npx create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to npx create-react-app globally but I couldn't find the right path. How will I helpful for avoiding every time npx create-react-app command.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The command for creating an new npx app is
"npx create-react-app my-app" in terminal.

But to avoid running his command, I would lie to suggest a simple script:
If you are using linux do these following steps:
1)Create .sh file and write the following in it:

#!/bin/bash
npx create-react-app my-app

2)Type his command in your terminal:
chmod +x .sh

3)Now whenever you wan to create a new app run he following command in terminal, change to the directory of the file before executing:
./.sh

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what will be the code for windows user.